# Error 'lxml not found, please install it' when trying to read html with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lxml, wikipedia

I'm trying the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(nominal)')
```

But it is giving me the error:

```
ImportError: lxml not found, please install it
```

Why after doing '''pip install lxml''' the error message keeps showing up? Should I use the 'import lxml' ?

Comment: Did you install it in the correct package manager? (so `pip3` for python3), or in your virtual environment?

Comment: I installed it in the Anaconda environment

Comment: Are you sure you installed it on the same conda environment that is running the code? What does running `conda list lxml` on the anaconda prompt return?

Comment: @JuanEstevez it returns lxml with the version 4.5.0

Comment: How are you running the code? If you are using jupyter lab try restarting the kernel.

Comment: I will try that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954802/python-importerror-lxml-not-found-please-install-it

Comment: If you're using Conda, why did you allegedly install lmxl using pip?

Comment: what's the disadvantage of using pip in Anaconda? It seems that restarting kernel solved the problem

Comment: @GustavoBakker Once upon a time installing packages with pip onto conda environments would not have worked. Nowadays it's usually no problem. I'm guessing you use Anaconda more as a package bundle than conda as a package manager. If that's the case I don't think you need to worry about it too much unless you encounter issues.