# Problem with extracting elements from the table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello I need some piece of advice how to deal with my problem. So the thing is, I want to scrape information from the given table, and add those sting into list as a singular elements.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    
site = "http://www.voltwo.webd.pl/1-indexy/index-5-opracowania/01-maturalne-KINEMATYKA.html"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site, headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features="html5lib")
table = soup.findAll('td')

data = [i.find('tr') for i in table if i.find('tr') and 'text']
print(data)
```

Comment: What problems or errors are you encountering?

Comment: I want to get all string from the table into string list; for example first row = [90, 2020, maj.czer, PP, zamknięte, 2/1,Po rzece płynie motorówka1] sth like that. I want to get rid of all \n and \t, of course without the gaps between words. Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `pandas` since this is tabular data you're dealing with?

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.voltwo.webd.pl/1-indexy/index-5-opracowania/01-maturalne-KINEMATYKA.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser").find("table")
df = pd.read_html(str(soup), skiprows=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
df = pd.concat(df).drop([7, 8], axis="columns")
columns = ["Lp", "Rok", "Forma", "Poziom", "Typ zadania", "Strona", "Zadanie"]
df.to_csv("table.csv", index=False, header=columns, encoding="utf-8")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I wanted to try your solution, but I can't even make the program start. I always get the same error 'ImportError: lxml not found, please install it', even though  I had installed this 'lxml'.

Comment: You sure you've installed the right module in the right environment? Are you using venv? Please share the full error traceback.

Comment: That's my error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/szymonm/PycharmProjects/web_scrap_usingBeautifulSoup/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    df = pd.read_html(str(soup))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 1101, in read_html
    displayed_only=displayed_only,

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 894, in _parse
    parser = _parser_dispatch(flav)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 851, in _parser_dispatch
    raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")
ImportError: lxml not found, please install it

Comment: Do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954802/python-importerror-lxml-not-found-please-install-it

Comment: I did it but still, it somehow doesn't want to be installed, from the terminal I get 'Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (4.5.0)'; I have python 3.6, latest pip, and I completely don't know what else could I have done. I also tried to install in via Pycharm and it doesn't see this lxml, even though pycharm says it's installed

Comment: Create a new venv in Pycharm and set up a fresh project iterpreter and then try installing both pandas and lxml

Comment: Thank you, I've done what you have recommended, and finally it worked. I very appreciate your help, especially that you helped me second time. Thank you!

Comment: Nie ma za co. ;)

Comment: coś przeczuwałem xD