# "ImportError: lxml not found, please install it" after installing lxml using VS Code

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio

I am using a virtual environment with python version 3.9.9 in VS Code and keep getting the same error even after I pip install lxml. I am able to do it successfully in jupyter notebook using python 3.8.8 but can't figure out how to do it in this new environment.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Thug'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

And here is my error:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> ml_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Thug'
>>> ml_df_original = pd.read_html(ml_url)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\main\pyenvs\py39ve\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\main\pyenvs\py39ve\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1113, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "C:\Users\main\pyenvs\py39ve\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 915, in _parse
    parser = _parser_dispatch(flav)
  File "C:\Users\main\pyenvs\py39ve\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 872, in _parser_dispatch
    raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")
ImportError: lxml not found, please install it
```

I tried all of the suggestions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954802/python-importerror-lxml-not-found-please-install-it) page and nothing worked. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

As we see in this [blog](https://blog.carlesmateo.com/tag/python-pandas-package/), miss install *lxml* package, try:

```
pip install lxml
```